# How to store Authorization Code in Nest Thermostat when PIN-based

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, firebase, nest-api

I am trying to implement Nest Thermostat in My Application i Can success fully create pin authentication code but

--->i struck in while storing that pin authentication code because after checking if condition if ([[url host] isEqualToString:[redirectURL host]]) then,

--->always condition fails if condition success then only i can store it and get access token by using it (as per library)

I did as per Nest Sample code and Library and online solutions no use I am looking for Picking hands

Plz Ref-fear my code

```
    - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

        NSURL *url = [request URL];
        NSURL *redirectURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:RedirectURL];

        if ([[url host] isEqualToString:[redirectURL host]])
        {
            NSString *urlResources = [url resourceSpecifier];
            urlResources = [urlResources stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:QUESTION_MARK withString:EMPTY_STRING];
            urlResources = [urlResources stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:HASHTAG withString:EMPTY_STRING];

            NSArray *urlResourcesArray = [urlResources componentsSeparatedByString:SLASH];

            NSString *urlParamaters = [urlResourcesArray objectAtIndex:([urlResourcesArray count]-1)];

            NSArray *urlParamatersArray = [urlParamaters componentsSeparatedByString:AMPERSAND];
            NSString *keyValue = [urlParamatersArray lastObject];
            NSArray *keyValueArray = [keyValue componentsSeparatedByString:EQUALS];

            if([[keyValueArray objectAtIndex:(0)] isEqualToString:@"code"]) {

                [self.delegate foundAuthorizationCode:[keyValueArray objectAtIndex:1]];

            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error retrieving the authorization code.");
            }
            return NO;
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

The webview which is showing pin that is only screen i can see. after that i struck it .Desperately needed help

Comment: any help about it would be great full.....

Comment: plz share the process of code is going to execute here..and some sample Redirect urls

Answer (score 0):

Use web base authentication and Fill the redirect url at the time of registering the client , this redirect url should not be empty on the client page,then once you enter the  device login credentials into your app then it automatically  redirect and gives the authentication token then with that authentication token access token will be provided , by using that access token you can get the device details